# Search for a word of a 2d grid of characters and replace the characters of that word in that 2d grid by hyphens

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I used a known algorithm to check if the words exist in the grid :

```
public boolean wordExists(String word, int row, int col) {

//all 8 directions
int[] x = {  -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 };
int[] y = { -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1 };

int rows = arrayLetters.length;
int cols = arrayLetters[0].length;

//Checking if the first character corresponds to the position row, col
if (arrayLetters[row][col] != word.charAt(0)) {
    return false;
}

int lenWord = word.length();

//looping through all 8 directions
for (int direction = 0; direction < 8; direction++) {
    int k = 0;
    int dirRow = row + x[direction];
    int dirCol = col + y[direction];
    
    //Because the first character is checked we then check if the following characters 
    //correspond to the word
    for (k = 1; k < lenWord; k++) {
        
        //Out of bounds
        if (dirRow >= rows || dirRow < 0 || dirCol >= cols|| dirCol < 0) {
            break;
        }
            

        // If not matched
        if (arrayLetters[dirRow][dirCol] != word.charAt(k)) {
            break;
        }
            
        //If everything is valid move in that particular direction
        dirRow += x[direction];
        dirCol += y[direction];
        
    }
    
    //if word exists k should be equal to the length of the word
    if (k == lenMot) {
        return true;
    }
    
}

//Otherwise
System.out.println("The word doesn't exist");

return false;
}
```

Then actually looking for the specific word if wordExists returns true and considering every possible position in the 2d array as a starting point:

```
 public void searchWord(String word) {   

    for (int row = 0; row < arrayLetters.length; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < arrayLetters[0].length; col++) {
          if (arrayLetters[row][col] == word.charAt(0) && wordExists(word, row, col)) {
              System.out.println("Word position : " + row + ", " + col);
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Now knowing this, how could I replace the found characters matching the word by hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there are couple of ways of doing that. One simple way would be to pass an array or something similar to pass on to the function and then populate it with the directions. If there is a match of the word then pass the array with all the directions in it. But in case there is no match then just return the empty array or don't populate anything (assuming if you are passing the reference). And now you can easily write another function or even in the same loop so that given the starting `row` and `col` you would just traverse the stored directions and fill them with `-`.

Not posting a code since it is also posted in `algortihm` tag. Taking the liberty of just giving the idea.